# Como calcular promedio de una lista string en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un `listado.txt` el cual al leerlo y guardarlo en una variable y colocarle un `print` a la variable me imprime eso ¿cómo puedo sacar el promedio de cada estudiante?

```
['Aquiles Baeza,5.1,2.0,4.8,7.0,6.1,4.7,6.1,5.4,3.8,3.7,6.6,6.1 \n', 
'Esteban Quito,6.1,6.6,6.3,7.0,6.0,6.8,6.7,5.5,5.4,6.3,6.5,6.8 \n', 
'Elsa Payo,3.0,2.1,3.9,4.5,3.6,4.2,3.7,4.8,1.3,1.5,2.4,3.3 \n', 
'Armando Casas,5.8,6.1,7.0,5.2,4.0,3.6,5.1,6.9,5.4,4.0,3.6,1.2\n']
```

Comment: Lo que tienes es una lista. Cada elemento es una línea del texto. Puedes separar cada línea en sus partes usando `split`. Eso te retorna otra lista. Descarta el primer elemento y te queda la lista de notas.

Comment: Hola @Felipe Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido por el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que revises las recomendaciones de [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y que incluyas un un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Según esa salida, es probable que ese archivo esté en formato CSV. Si es así, python [tiene módulos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para trabajar nativamente en formato CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que como indica @aeportugal en los comentarios, usando los módulos adecuados en la lectura del fichero puedas tener una estructura de datos más sencilla de usar. Si incluyes el código que usaste para leer el fichero podríamos revisar otras opciones de solución.

Ahora bien, partiendo de tu lista de valores, puedes formatear el texto para obtener los resultados que buscas, así:

1. Creamos la lista con el formato que indicas:

   ```
   import statistics as stats

    text= ['Aquiles Baeza,5.1,2.0,4.8,7.0,6.1,4.7,6.1,5.4,3.8,3.7,6.6,6.1 \n', 'Esteban Quito,6.1,6.6,6.3,7.0,6.0,6.8,6.7,5.5,5.4,6.3,6.5,6.8 \n', 'Elsa Payo,3.0,2.1,3.9,4.5,3.6,4.2,3.7,4.8,1.3,1.5,2.4,3.3 \n', 'Armando Casas,5.8,6.1,7.0,5.2,4.0,3.6,5.1,6.9,5.4,4.0,3.6,1.2\n']
    lines=[]
    diccionario={}
   ```
2. Recorremos la lista `text` con un ciclo `for` y por cada posición de la lista inicial, limpiamos los `\n` y dividimos por el separamos `","`. Y asignamos los valores transformados en una nueva lista que he llamado `lines` así:

```
    for i in text:
        lines.append((i.replace('\n','')).split(',')) 
    print(lines)
```

El resultado de `lines` en este punto es:

```
[['Aquiles Baeza', '5.1', '2.0', '4.8', '7.0', '6.1', '4.7', '6.1', '5.4', '3.8', '3.7', '6.6', '6.1 '], ['Esteban Quito', '6.1', '6.6', '6.3', '7.0', '6.0', '6.8', '6.7', '5.5', '5.4', '6.3', '6.5', '6.8 '], ['Elsa Payo', '3.0', '2.1', '3.9', '4.5', '3.6', '4.2', '3.7', '4.8', '1.3', '1.5', '2.4', '3.3 '], ['Armando Casas', '5.8', '6.1', '7.0', '5.2', '4.0', '3.6', '5.1', '6.9', '5.4', '4.0', '3.6', '1.2']]
```

3. Finalmente, recorremos la nueva lista `lines` y para cada una de sus posiciones separamos los nombres de los valores (sabemos que los nombres ahora están en la posición cero y los valores a partir de la posición 1). Pasamos los valores a float y finalmente calculamos la media de valores:

   ```
   for line in lines:
    diccionario["Nombre"]=line[0]
    diccionario["Valor"] = list(float(i) for i in line[1:])
    print(diccionario["Nombre"]," ", stats.mean(diccionario["Valor"]))
   ```

El resultado final sería:

```
Aquiles Baeza   5.116666666666666
Esteban Quito   6.333333333333333
Elsa Payo   3.191666666666667
Armando Casas   4.825
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
text = ['Aquiles Baeza,5.1,2.0,4.8,7.0,6.1,4.7,6.1,5.4,3.8,3.7,6.6,6.1 \n', 
'Esteban Quito,6.1,6.6,6.3,7.0,6.0,6.8,6.7,5.5,5.4,6.3,6.5,6.8 \n', 
'Elsa Payo,3.0,2.1,3.9,4.5,3.6,4.2,3.7,4.8,1.3,1.5,2.4,3.3 \n', 
'Armando Casas,5.8,6.1,7.0,5.2,4.0,3.6,5.1,6.9,5.4,4.0,3.6,1.2\n']

for l in text:
    nombre,*notas = l.split(",")
    print(f'{nombre} {sum(map(float,notas))/len(notas)}')
```